# Is it ok to have multiple models for REST API?

Tags: java, rest, design-patterns, model, retrofit

In my project, there is one model for a user in the database. Now, I have multiple requests to get specific users. I can get `bestUsers` which response contains list of JSON's with fewer fields (only these which are needed) - the list of these users is calculated by the server-side algorithm. Now, in the client-side: should I have two models `User` - for general usage and `UserBest` - to list the best users or just have one model and serialize only the fields which appear in the JSON (the rest will be null).

I'm writing in Java and using the retrofit library.

Comment: I would say, there should one model only to represent your user rather than having multiple models

Answer (score 3):

If you want the client to be strongly typed and always be in sync with the server, meaning any "illegal" data would be a sign of an error, create multiple models and parse the requests strictly.

If you want to add data to the backend's model without having to change the client at the same time or leave out data at will, you can use a single model that ignores any missing or additional data.

Both are viable options depending on your needs. In a production grade serious application you would probably prefer the strong typing of the first option, in a "less serious" application the latter could save you a little time and typing (and deploying, if you want to add data to the backend model first and frontend later).

I'm assuming the "model" in the backend refers to the API response, since the actual model can be anything and you're only returning views of the model in a DTO.

Comment: Great answer! The API response can give me different fields from the model in the backend (in the database). Those specific request which gives json with less data serves me basically for listing entities with only some data. I've got your point, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion It's totally ok to have your model in the Back-end and in the Front-end. Besides that is rarely that a Front-end model to be equal to a Back-end model because each represent abstraction of different things.

#### The Back-End model

Holds the logical and general abstraction of an entity

#### The Front-End model

Represents an entity in the Front-End. Many of these models are similar to the Back-End ones, but they are rarely exactly the same, plus in Front-End we might need additional entities used to interact with the user